# How to extract a JSON object from div tag in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to extract the JSON content from a `<div>` tag but got some error:

> matches = jsonx.search(data) TypeError: expected string or bytes-like
>   object

```
import re

html = """ 
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    <div id="data"><!--  {"activity": {"type":"read"}} --></div>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    </body>
    </html>
"""

jsonx = re.compile('<div id="data"><!--({.*?})--></div>', re.DOTALL)
matches = jsonx.search(html)
print(matches.group(1))
```

How can I got just the json like this:

```
{"activity": {"type":"read"}}
```

Comment: paste in your div with contents here : https://regex101.com/
then trial and error match the pattern that you need, the resulting regex pattern should be what you can then use in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code I do not get the `TypeError`. It suggests that the input you are giving to `jsonx.search` is not the html string you posted.

Nevertheless, I changed the regex to cut the json out of the html string you posted:

```
import re

html = """
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    <div id="data"><!--  {"activity": {"type":"read"}} --></div>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    </body>
    </html>
"""

jsonx = re.compile('<div id="data"><!--(.*?)--></div>', re.DOTALL)  # removed curly braces
matches = jsonx.search(html)
print(matches.group(1).strip())  # added .strip() to remove surrounding spaces
```

**Output:**

```
{"activity": {"type":"read"}}
```

If you have to parse more parts of an HTML document I recommend to use a library like [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your regular expression if you refactor it to

```
re.compile(r'<div id="data"><!-- *(\{.*\}) *--></div>', re.DOTALL)
```

The rest of your code works without issues. The summary of the changes I made to your regular expression is the following:

Escaped `{` and `}` characters, as these represent things already in a regular expression and needs to be escaped to make an exact match.

Added `*` to the beginning and end of your comment as your example shows that can be one or more spaces in between the data comment tags and the actual JSON.

Removed `?` after `*` in the expression `({.*?})` because `*` already implies optional capturing.